# How to exclude row data based on equal values in same view?

Tags: mysql, view

Given simple view

```
reports.uid,
reports.mail,
reports.jobcode,
reports.jobcodedescr,
reports.regionname,
reports.supervisorid,
reports.supemail

FROM
reports_accredit_fscore_allmanagers
```

How can I exclude rows where the uid on a row is not anywhere in the supervisorid list?  I have tried several context but I keep getting my entire list.  Right now that view has 440 employees and 113 supervisors.  So the list I should get should be 327 but not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one option using `not exists`:

```
select uid, mail, jobcode, jobcodedescr, regionname, supervisorid, supemail
from reports_accredit_fscore_allmanagers r
where not exists (
    select 1
    from reports_accredit_fscore_allmanagers r2
    where r.uid = r2.supervisorid
)
```

And here's an `outer join / null` check:

```
select r.uid, r.mail, r.jobcode, r.jobcodedescr, 
       r.regionname, r.supervisorid, r.supemail
from reports_accredit_fscore_allmanagers r
    left join reports_accredit_fscore_allmanagers r2 on r.uid = r2.supervisorid
where r2.supervisorid is null
```

Comment: The first example worked great.  I thought I was having a brain dead day and couldn't get an outer join to work.  It was a little bit more complex than I thought and I don't think I have constructed a where not exists using an alias in a couple years.  You definitely lose it if you don't use it.